# Perform IEnumerable method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Simplying the problem statement to List of int, lets say I have this

```
 List<int> range = new List<int>(10) { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
```

User inputs 24, I would need a Early feed value as 20 and late feed value as 30
User inputs 99, I would need a Early feed value as 90 and late feed value as 100
**User inputs 20, I would need a Early feed value as 20 and late feed value as 20**

Is there a Lamba Expression or linq statement to get this sort of result.

My real input is not List of int, I have just simlified it, more keen on the lamba or linq expression to get the result

Comment: Will the input always be sorted?

Comment: What if user input -10 or 10 ?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
range.Where(i => i <= UserInput).Max();
```

and

```
range.Where(i => i >= UserInput).Min();
```

Or Alternatively

```
range.Max(i => i <= UserInput);
range.Min(i => i >= UserInput);
```

Comment: Good start but, you need to add the rule for value 20

Comment: This can be simplified: `Where(<expression>).Max/Min()` is equivalent to `Max/Min(<expression>)`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I always forget that for some reason!